# Some jQuery code not working in VS2012, but works fine in VS2010

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

We just upgraded our code to .Net 4.5 and are using VS2012 now, but some jQuery code doesn't work anymore. For example, in a page we have a checkbox within a DataGrid.

Code to get the list of checkboxes:

```
$('input:checkbox[id$=MappingGrdCb]').each(function() {
    //....
}
```

This works fine in VS2010, `$('input:checkbox[id$=MappingGrdCb]')` returns an array of checkboxes, but in VS2012, it's empty.

Anybody can help me on this? thanks a lot!

Comment: has the jquery version changed?

Comment: Changing Visual Studio versions would not change outputs. There must be some other issue in your code.

Comment: What is the actual Id of the DataGrid in the markup when you run the project?

Comment: <asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="EmaiTemGrd"....
  <ItemTemplate> 
   <asp:CheckBox ID="MappingGrdCb" runat="server" Checked="true" />

Comment: Maybe this might not solve the problem , but try this instead $('input:checkbox[id*="MappingGrdCb"]')

Comment: @Andrew Sorry, I meant the Id that gets generated on the actual control in the HTML when you run the project (check the source of the page).

Comment: When I run it, the real id for DataGrid and Checkbox: Content_LeadExportLE_TemMappingGrd, Content_LeadExportLE_TemMappingGrd_MappingGrdCb_1

Comment: Thanks Sushanth, your code works! but why? my code works fine before, in this case, I need to check the all the other jquery code? they're huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `ends with selector` try this     `Attribute contains selector`

```
$('input:checkbox[id*="MappingGrdCb"]')
```

Comment: Thanks Sushanth, your code works! but why? my code works fine before, in this case, I need to check all the other jquery code? there're many pages, huge jquery code...

Comment: Maybe the way the elements rendered that have the runat="server" attribute are being appended or prepended some other placeholders to it.. So using a `*` will solve the issue in such cases

Comment: This may be relevant (though older versions of upgrades between VS 2003 and VS 2005): http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/10/gotcha-don-t-use-xhtmlconformance-mode-legacy-with-asp-net-ajax.aspx

Comment: To avoid this I think you have an option if ClientMode="Static" .. If you add this then content plcaholders will not be appended